# help in php button

Tags: php, button

i have a this button

```
<input type="button" name="continue" id="continue" value="Continue">
```

in php we use if($_POST['continue']) to edit the action of the submit button but only if its type is "submit". what if its type is "button"? how can i edit the action of that button?

Comment: Your question is unclear and uses the wrong terms. Do you mean the action of the form, the value of the button...May be you need Javascript and not PHP. Please rephrase the question

Comment: this is what i'm trying to do. i have a form with a textarea and a button. using jquery, i have a dialog that should only appear when the textarea is not empty. how can i do that?

Comment: Between your question and your elaboration I'm utterly confused. Could you incorporate that into your question and elaborate as much as possible? The more information you provide the better the help you will get.

Answer (score 1):

If the type of the button is "`button`" instead of "`submit`", you will need another button to submit the form. consider this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="continue" id="continue" value="Continue" />
<input type="submit" name="go" id="go" value="Next" />
```

In that way, you can modify the value of the `$_POST['continue']` without affecting the User Interface (UI).